# Drag and drop component return only source code

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to make use of the custom form with drag and drop, where the user takes input fields, select boxes, checkboxes, etc, and create own form.

Problem is when I in the DRAG zone create reusable components and take it to the DROP zone I only see source code...
[Here is the working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9kjw6-vkqbnf?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html). Try to move from roles to list 1 some elements.

Thanks In advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when binding a URL in an  hyperlink, someValue will be sanitized so that an attacker cannot inject e.g. a javascript: URL that would execute code on the website.You should trust the HTML first before injecting it. You have to use the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) for such a thing.

```
export class injectComponent  {

    private _inputdata: string = '<input type="text" name="fname">';

    public get inputdata() : SafeHtml {
       return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._inputdata);
    }

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
}
```

and in html

```
<div [innerHTML]="inputdata"></div>
```

i have edited your example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9kjw6-em4rhw)